# Sharing domain classes in Spring roo generated code and Android app

Tags: android, spring-roo

I am writing a web service, the code for which is generated using Spring roo. In Parallel I am also writing an android client for the web service.

I want to share the domain classes in both these projects, since the Spring roo code is dispersed in Java and (.aj) files, I am looking for best practice to share the domain classes in Webservice project and android project, so that I dont have to manually write domain classes in the android project.

I am using Spring STS for both Webservice project and Android project.

I would appreciate any help in this matter

Thanks